# Traefik cannot read private key error

Tags: docker, certificate

I created a new XM1 developer environment using the official [Container Deployment Package](https://github.com/Sitecore/container-deployment/releases/tag/sxp%2F10.3.1.009452.1448), using PowerShell 7.3.6 elevated.  After running Compose-Init.ps1 and `docker compose up -d`, when trying to hit https://xm1cm.localhost I receive a certificate error, because the site is served using the Traefik Default Certificate, rather than the signed one created by the compose-init.ps1 process. Examining the Traefik logs shows this error:

```
level=error msg="Unable to append certificate -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n[key removed]\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n to store: unable to generate TLS certificate : tls: failed to parse private key" tlsStoreName=default
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be related to an incompatibility with `SitecoreDockerTools` and `PowerShell 7.3`. A colleague (Jason Bert) was able to get past this by running with `PowerShell 5.1` (though I run into a separate issue there).

I was able to resolve this by using the "**mkcert**" utility as documented here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/run-your-first-sitecore-instance.html

```
mkcert -cert-file traefik\certs\xm1cm.localhost.crt -key-file traefik\certs\xm1cm.localhost.key "xm1cm.localhost"
```

for CM, CD, and ID roles.

Reported to Sitecore as a defect (`CS0399761`).

---

** When I tried to run `compose-init.ps1` with PowerShell 5.1, I ran into this error:

```
> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 
'AllowPrerelease'.
```

So neither PowerShell 5.1 nor 7.3 runs cleanly.

Comment: Using `mkcert` for all 3 certificates and adding them to `Trusted` certificates did the trick for me.

Comment: To add a little bit of additional information, I experienced the same thing and was able to use mkcert to fix it.
I noticed a difference between the packages provided by Sitecore through dev.sitecore.net (the Container Deployment Package) and the docker examples on github: https://github.com/Sitecore/docker-examples
The init.ps1 file from Github already contains mkcert while the compose-init.ps1 from the Sitecore site doesn't